# Interaction between button in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple Tkinter GUI using Python. The user interface has 3 different buttons: Yes, No and Print.

If the user click button Yes then click button Print, a line will appear "Yes is 1" in the user interface.

If the user un-click Yes, then "No", then click Print, a line will appear "No is 0" in the user interface

If user only click Yes, nothing will be shown.

But how can the program can know which button the user click? Which function can I use to find the connection between these two related button? How the code is performed?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you looked at any tkinter tutorials? Have you looked at how *event driven programming* works?

Comment: I think you need to use a `Checkbutton` and `indicatoron` option. Keep in mind, this is not write-code-service. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @TheLizzard, yes I have some basic knowledge about tkinter that I understand how to create button that has command=function, but there's nothing seem to match my question, or that I don't know which term I should search for.

Comment: @mylearning `tkinter` is a library that uses event driven programming. Basically the function is called when the user presses the button. You just need to use global variables as flags so that the different function can know what was pressed

Comment: @Tkinter: yes, I could create the function for all buttons Print, Yes and No, but need the if-else clause, and I don't know which command showing that the user has clicked Yes?so that when click Print, the user interface will print a different line than clicking on No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```py
import tkinter as tk

text_to_be_printed = None

def yes_pressed():
    global text_to_be_printed
    text_to_be_printed = "yes"
    results_label.config(text="")

def no_pressed():
    global text_to_be_printed
    text_to_be_printed = "no"
    results_label.config(text="")

def print_pressed():
    # If you want to print the text to the console:
    # print(text_to_be_printed)
    results_label.config(text=text_to_be_printed)


root = tk.Tk()

results_label = tk.Label(root, text="")

yes_button = tk.Button(root, text="yes", command=yes_pressed)
no_button = tk.Button(root, text="no", command=no_pressed)
print_button = tk.Button(root, text="print", command=print_pressed)

yes_button.pack()
no_button.pack()
print_button.pack()
results_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It uses 3 functions that are called when the corresponding button is pressed. It also uses a flag `text_to_be_printed` that contains the data that should be printed on the screen. Please note that it is a global variable.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. It's really what I was looking for, except that I'm not familiar with global variable :( but I will search for it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did. I made a variable to check if the yes button is pressed. When no is pressed, it checks if yes was pressed. If yes, it will print "Yes is 1", then adds 1 to the number of presses. This is so when the process happens again, it doesn't print "yes is 1"; instead prints "yes is 0".

**Code:**

```py
from tkinter import *


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.yes_pressed = False
        self.no_pressed = False
        self.num_presses = 0

        self.yes_button = Button(root, text='yes', command=self.yes_button_pressed)
        self.no_button = Button(root, text='no', command=self.no_button_pressed)
        self.print_button = Button(root, text='print', command=self.print_button_pressed)

        self.yes_button.pack()
        self.no_button.pack()
        self.print_button.pack()

    def yes_button_pressed(self):
        self.yes_pressed = not self.yes_pressed
        self.num_presses += 1

    def print_button_pressed(self):
        if self.yes_pressed and self.num_presses %2 != 0:
            print("Yes is 1")
            print(self.no_pressed)
            self.yes_pressed = False

        if self.no_pressed:
            print("Yes is 0")
            self.no_pressed = False

    def no_button_pressed(self):
        if self.num_presses % 2 == 0:
            self.no_pressed = True
        else:
            self.no_pressed = False


root = Tk()
GUI()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi! It's not the answer I was looking for. The program needs 3 different buttons, that Print is also a button. If user click both Yes and Print then a line will be shown on the user interface. If user click only Yes, nothing will be shown.

Comment: please see updated code

Comment: You really did not have to do this much calculation, if you use `Checkbutton`.